# weblogic security realm with spring security filters

Tags: spring, security, weblogic

I am using spring security 3.1.1  for authentication.Application is deployed in weblogic server with security realm enabled for accessing datasource. for servlets I can give 
    `<run-as>`
    `<role-name>testrole</role-name>`
    `</run-as>`

how do i do the same for spring security filters. I am getting this error while accessing datasource from filters

### : User "" does not have permission to perform operation "reserve" on resource "jdbc/DataSource"

securityContext.xml

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<sec:http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" >
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"/>
<sec:custom-filter position="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref="LogoutFilter" />
<sec:custom-filter position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="AuthenticationFilter"/>
</sec:http>
<bean id="LogoutFilter" class="com.xxx.LogoutFilter">
<constructor-arg>
<bean class="com.xxx.LogoutSuccessHandler"></bean>
</constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg>
<list>
<bean class="com.xxx.LogoutHandler"></bean>
</list>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="AuthenticationFilter" class="com.xxx.AuthenticationFilter" >
<constructor-arg type="java.lang.String">
<value>/login.do</value>
</constructor-arg>
<property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
<property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler" />
<property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler" />
</bean>

<bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
<property name="loginFormUrl" value="/common/dologin.jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="successHandler" class="com.xxx.AuthSuccessHandler"/>
<bean id="failureHandler" class="com.xxx.AuthFailureHandler"/>

<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
<sec:authentication-provider ref="jaasAuthenticationProvider" />
</sec:authentication-manager>


<bean id="jaasAuthenticationProvider"
class="com.xxx.JaasAuthenticationProvider">

<property name="callbackHandlers">
<list>
<bean class="com.xxx.security.callback.SecurityInfoProvider">
</bean>
</list>
</property>
<property name="authorityGranters">
<list>
<bean class="com.xxx.security.action.RoleUserAuthorityGranter" />
</list>
</property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Can you show us your spring security context configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you could consider a solution as the following.

```
    <bean id="securedJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
         <property name="environment">
             <props>
                 <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">t3://myServerA:8001,myServerB:8002</prop>
                 <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
                 <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">weblogic</prop>
                 <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">weblogic</prop>
             </props>
         </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="targetDatasource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
         <property name="jndiTemplate">
              <ref local="securedJndiTemplate"/>
         </property>
         <property name="jndiName">
              <value>myWeblogicJNDI</value>
         </property>
    </bean>
```

In your java code try to lookup the targetDatasource.

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: I will go with this approach but is there any other way of passing the role defined in web.xml to the request ? like the way it happens when I define it for servlet.

Comment: I'm not aware of a similar way like using the run-as role tags for servlets. If you discover such a way please post it so that we will be informed. Thanks